# Core Data search in different enteties

Tags: ios, search, core-data

I use a search controller in my app. The user types in a word and I return a list of Core Data entities, where each has a title containing that word. That's easy.

But I also want to return at the bottom of this list other entities that have the search word as their title and are in to-many relationship with those in which I searched first.

So if I don't find the search word in the title, I want to search in the titles of the entities related to the first entity type.

Is this possible with a single NSPredicate?

Here is my Core Data model

[image: Code Data model diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two types of entity: `Term` and `Part`. You want a list structured like this:

- First all the `Term` entities with `title` == title
- Then all the `Part` entities with `title` == title

If this is correct, you won't be able to fetch both parts of the list with one `NSFetchRequest`. The easiest way is to perform two separate fetches and just append the second list to the first. If you add more structure to your data, you might be able to accomplish this in one fancy request, but as far as I can see, it wouldn't be worth it. If you have massive amounts of data, you should of course think about clever ways to index it.

Answer (score 5):

As an aside you should NEVER use one way relationships.  They are bad for performance and Xcode should be screaming at you via warnings about them.  Don't ignore warnings.

For the search, I would follow what @Felixyz said, two fetches and merge the results.  If the data becomes voluminous then you will want to split "search title" into a separate object with relationships and just search against that.

Fix your relationships though.  Even if *you* never use them, Core Data will.